# Laravel Backpack basic request validation

Tags: laravel-backpack

I'm having an issue that I thought would be VERY simple to accomplish. I can not get this very basic request validation to work. I can enter "Bob" on the create form and the edit form and get no error messages. It simply inserts into the database.

Here's my code. I feel I'm doing/not doing something stupid.

**UserCrudController.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Requests\UserRequest;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanelFacade as CRUD;

/**
 * Class UserCrudController
 * @package App\Http\Controllers\Admin
 * @property-read \Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanel $crud
 */
class UserCrudController extends CrudController
{
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ListOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\CreateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\UpdateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\DeleteOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ShowOperation;

    /**
     * Configure the CrudPanel object. Apply settings to all operations.
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function setup()
    {
        CRUD::setModel(\App\Models\User::class);
        CRUD::setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/user');
        CRUD::setEntityNameStrings('user', 'users');
    }

    /**
     * Define what happens when the List operation is loaded.
     * 
     * @see  https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/crud-operation-list-entries
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupListOperation()
    {
        CRUD::column('name');
        CRUD::column('email');
        //CRUD::column('password');

        /**
         * Columns can be defined using the fluent syntax or array syntax:
         * - CRUD::column('price')->type('number');
         * - CRUD::addColumn(['name' => 'price', 'type' => 'number']); 
         */
    }

    /**
     * Define what happens when the Create operation is loaded.
     * 
     * @see https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/crud-operation-create
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupCreateOperation()
    {
        CRUD::setValidation(UserRequest::class);

        CRUD::field('name');
        CRUD::field('email');
        //CRUD::field('password');

        /**
         * Fields can be defined using the fluent syntax or array syntax:
         * - CRUD::field('price')->type('number');
         * - CRUD::addField(['name' => 'price', 'type' => 'number'])); 
         */
    }

    /**
     * Define what happens when the Update operation is loaded.
     * 
     * @see https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/crud-operation-update
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupUpdateOperation()
    {
        $this->setupCreateOperation();
    }
}
```

UserRequest.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        // only allow updates if the user is logged in
        return backpack_auth()->check();
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => ['required','min:5','max:255'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation attributes that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function attributes()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation messages that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry Bob. I've looked at this yesterday. I've looked at this today. I've compared it with something I've generated... it's identical... We're missing something here... This is odd... I've asked more people to look at this. But until they do, maybe you can do a `dd($this->crud)` after fields are defined. What's inside the `settings` attribute? Is the request properly registered in `settings.create.formRequest`? Is the `name` field in  `settings.create.requiredFields`?

Comment: dd doesn't do anything in the controller. It made me realize though that the controller isn't even being called even though it's defined in the routes. 

Pedro's answer below pointed me in the right direction though. The UserCrudController from the PermissionManager package is being run and it's calling the package's UserFormRequest instead of mine

Unfortunately, I tried his AppServiceProvidor suggestion and that just makes the system use my UserCrudController only and I lose all the permissions functionality.

Comment: If you lose functionality is because your `UserCrudController` does not extend the `PackageCrudController`. 
I've updated my answer to add that bit, I wrote it, but maybe I was not clear enough. 
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening is that you are not loading that controller.

If you have installed `PermissionManager` and now want to configure the `UserCrudController` you need to either manually register the routes yourself and point to your new controller, or alternativelly (and probably recommended) bind your new controller to the package one so your controller gets "served" instead of the package controller.

```php
// In AppServiceProvider.php or any other provider of your choice:

$this->app->bind(
    \Backpack\PermissionManager\app\Http\Controllers\UserCrudController::class,
    \App\Http\Controllers\Admin\UserCrudController::class
);
```

If you don't need to change everything in the Controller you can directly extend the package `UserCrudController` and only change the things you need.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

class UserCrudController extends \Backpack\PermissionManager\app\Http\Controllers\UserCrudController
{
}
```

The package controller already extends the `CrudController`.

The validation is added on `setupCreateOperation()` that you can override to fit your needs.

Cheers